# Log calls return NaN in C

Tags: c, math, logarithm

I have an array of double:

```
double theoretical_distribution[] = {1/21, 2/21, 3/21, 4/21, 5/21, 6/21};
```

And I am trying to computer it's entropy as:

```
double entropy = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(theoretical_distribution)/sizeof(*theoretical_distribution); i++) {
    entropy -= (theoretical_distribution[i] * (log10(theoretical_distribution[i])/log10(arity))); 
}
```

However I am getting NaN, I have checked the part

```
(theoretical_distribution[i] * (log10(theoretical_distribution[i])/log10(arity)))
```

And found it to return NaN itself, so I assume it's the culprit, however all it's supposed to be is a simple base conversion of the log? Am I missing some detail about the maths of it?
Why is it evaluating to NaN.

Comment: `1/21` --> `1.0/21` ditto.

Comment: Integer division truncates, resulting in 0. Log of 0 is NaN.

Comment: @Mark Ransom "Log of 0 is NaN"  or perhaps  -INF.  The rest of OP's equation makes the NaN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing `0` to the `log10` function.

This is because your array `theoretical_distribution` is being populated with constant values that result from integer computations, all of which have a denominator larger than the numerator.

You probably intended floating computations, so make at least one of the numerator or denominator a floating constant.

Comment: Yep, that did it! Thank you. Also Shoutout to @BLUEPIXY, who was fastest to respond.